# Show a Category in Left-Side Menu Only?

Tags: category, menu

The original post is further down but I would like to rephrase it for clarity:

We use both top & left-side navigation on Magento CE and I want to add the MAIN category to our left-side navigation ONLY.

Now, the way things are currently configured (or customized) is when you create a new Main Category and set **Visible in Nav** to (Yes) it is added to BOTH top navigation & left-side navigation.

Conversely, if you set **Visible in Nav** to (No) it is removed from BOTH top navigation & left-side navigation.

So how can I show the Main Category in one BUT not the other? I have looked at left.phtml & top.phtml too. Thank you all again in helping resolve this question.

**=> Original Post:**

Our Magento CE site is customized to show Categories in both the top & left-side menus. So, how do I show a Category ONLY in the left-side menu? I have looked through left.phtml & top.phtml here: /html/app/design/frontend/default/ourtheme/template/catalog/navigation to no avail as well as dozens of other files. I can't seem to figure this out. Can you help me? Thank You.

Comment: To clarify, below is an example of what I want to accomplish. Notice that the ROOT Categories 5 & 8 ONLY appear in the sidebar menu. Currently, when I add a Root Category it is added to BOTH sidebar & main menus. How do I make the appropriate changes??? Thank You! - *(MAIN MENU) Cat 1 | Cat 7 | Cat 9 *(SIDEBAR/LEFT MENU) Cat 1 - Cat 5 - Cat 8 - Cat 7 - Cat 9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had same problem, after some coding I made this in template/catalog/navigation/left.phtml:

first line:

> `<?php $ct = Mage::registry('current_category')->getID(); ?>`

in the end of the file(before endif;)

```
<?php elseif( $ct == 92 || $ct == 85 || $ct == 224): ?>
<?php
$currentcategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
$subcategorys = explode(',' , $currentcategory->getChildren());


?>

<div class="block block-layered-nav">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Browse By') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <dl id="narrow-by-list2">
            <dt><?php echo $this->__('Category') ?></dt>
            <dd>
                <ol>
                <?php foreach($subcategorys as $cat): ?>
                     <?php $cate =  Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat); ?>
                    <li>

                        <a href="<?php echo $cate->getUrl()?>" <?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($cate)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($cate->getName()) ?>(<?php echo $cate->getProductCount() ?>) </a>                  
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ol>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list2')</script>
    </div>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Please do not `load()` in a loop, this is a performance killer. Rather use a collection: `$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')->addIdFilter($subcategorys); foreach ($collection as $cate) { ...`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *remove a category from top menu* and then want to *show it only in left  side*,  then Go to

```
Catalog  >  Manage Category  > [Select  a  category]  > General Information (tab)  >  Include in Navigation Menu
```

and set it to `No`.

Comment: Thank you but I already tried that. Selecting "No" removes it from the left-side menu yet leaves it in the top menu. I want to do the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As shown in the above image.please select `Is Anchor to Yes` of each categories from the Display Settings.

Then Your category will come in the left side.

If this answer helped you.please upvote and accept this answer Please

Comment: Setting "Is Anchor to Yes" had no effect and neither does selecting "No" for "Include in Navigation Menu". What that did was remove the 'Category' from the left-side menu 'ONLY' while leaving it in the 'Top' Menu. I want to do the opposite. Any other help? Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Solved after some research & thought I would share! To recap, our site (Magento CE Platform) is programmed to add MAIN CATEGORIES to both top nav & left-side nav when "Visible in Nav" is set to "Yes". But I didn't want to show ALL MAIN CATEGORIES in the top navigation which I solved using the following PHP Array. I'm sure this is simple coding because I'm a beginner but there it is none the less:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
<!-- show categories in top nav not in following array -->
<?php if (!in_array($_category->getId(), array(738, 383, 392, 328, 389))) : ?> 
<?php echo $this->drawItem2($_category) ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```